# <com.google.ads.AdView gives me: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: adview

Hi have already several apps with AdView, but this time, I can't see what is wrong. 
When I look at the file in Eclipse in Graphical Layout, it shows the AdView placeholder in the right size and place but with the Error message: 
Could not initialize AdView. Required XML attribute, "adSize" missing.

Please take a look on my code and hopefully somebody see what I'm missing.

Here is the code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/eifelturm"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newbutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:text="@string/neuesFoto"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:onClick="newPhoto"
        ></Button>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_listview">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="a1501d20d464e5d"
    app:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to reply, but I think your problem was that you were using the keyword `app` instead of `ads` in your AdView definition. With this structure it should work:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a1501d20d464e5d"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```